# update multiple tables with trigger

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, triggers

I want to update two tables when a user wants to update a view.

```
create trigger update_mID
instead of update of mID on LateRating
for each row
begin
    update Movie, Rating
    set mID = new.mID
    where mID = Old.mID;
end;
```

I want to update bot the Movie relation and the Rating relation, however, I have not yet experienced a trigger that is able to update multiple tables. Can someone please indicate how I can overcome this?

UPDATE: This is for a exercise to test my trigger scripting skills. The requirement is that I have to write it in one trigger query. @CL. I tried putting two update statements between the begin and end keywords, however, it says that there is a syntax error.... is there a specific way to put two updates between the begin and end?

Comment: maybe have them as two seperate sql update statements

Comment: Just to make sure, do you pretend update `mID` field in table `Movie`and in table `Rating`? If so simply put, @CL answer between `BEGIN` and `END;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `UPDATE` statement can modify only a single table.

Use two `UPDATE`s:

```
UPDATE Movie  SET mID = NEW.mID WHERE mID = OLD.mID;
UPDATE Rating SET mID = NEW.mID WHERE mID = OLD.mID;
```

Comment: @Olayinka To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: this is exactly the same question I have. Asking a new question would imply a duplicate.

Comment: @Olayinka It works for me and SeekingAlpha, so you are doing something different. Comments are not the right place to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a `REPLACE INTO` statement like the following:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_mID`;CREATE DEFINER=`USER`@`localhost` TRIGGER 
`update_mID` AFTER UPDATE ON `tblname` FOR EACH ROW REPLACE INTO 
USER_DATABASENAME.TBLNAME (COLUMNNAME1,COLUMNNAME1) SELECT COLUMNNAME1,COLUMNNAME1 
FROM USER_DBNAME.TBLNAME
```

This can even be two separate databases like the example below:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_mID`;CREATE DEFINER=`USER`@`localhost` TRIGGER 
`update_mID` AFTER UPDATE ON `tblname from DB1` FOR EACH ROW REPLACE INTO 
USER_DATABASENAME1.TBLNAMEDB2 (COLUMNNAME1,COLUMNNAME1) SELECT 
COLUMNNAME1,COLUMNNAME1 FROM USER_DBNAME2.TBLNAME
```